# Drawable color changes, but after changing activity remains

Tags: android

I have a menu, with several buttons and its drawables. This menu is included in 4 activitys.

I am setting the drawable color programmatically:

`mDrawable.setColorFilter (0xff0099cc, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);`

The first button by default is enabled, so the color is changed programmatically. When I press another button to go to another activity, the other button changes the color, but the first one remains as if it had activated.

[image: second button clicked, but the first was enabled, when change activity]

Answer (score 0):

You are not clear about your drawable and so I ll give generic solution to you.

You can  just use Drawable.setColorFilter( 0xffff0000, Mode.MULTIPLY ). If you could make the entire image WHITE (FFFFFF) so that when you do PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY, you end up with the correct colors. Note this would not affect the transparent pixels.

For solid images, it is best to use the color filter PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP because it will overlay the color on top of the source image, allowing you to change the color to the exact color you are looking for.

Let me know, whether it helps.